# API Gateway - Can't create mapping template from openapi doc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I have a mapping template that's pretty simple. I verified it works when I *manually* upload the template to the gateway.

```
#set($variable = $util.escapeJavaScript($method.request.header.some_variable))
```

When I include it as part of the `x-amazon-api-gateway-integration`, it doesn't get included:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responseTemplates: 
          application/json: #set($variable = $util.escapeJavaScript($method.request.header.some_variable))
```

The response template doc is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-responseTemplates.html

(I've tried various combinations of escape characters for quotes as well)

Whenever I upload this doc, the API gets updated but the mapping template is always left blank no matter the content I put in that field. What am I doing incorrectly?